# Convert Python PBKDF2HMAC to Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, openssl, pbkdf2, kdf

I have the following in python and want to transfer this to ruby. but i don't get it working. The original source is from here: https://github.com/HurricaneLabs/splunksecrets/blob/177d350a9164791c66139d11b4c63f5db83710b6/splunksecrets.py#L112

My "secret" is : `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

Python

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=b"disk-encryption",
    iterations=1,
    backend=default_backend()
)
key = kdf.derive(secret[:254])

print("KDF: %s" % key)
```

Ruby

```
  require 'openssl'

  kdf = OpenSSL::KDF.pbkdf2_hmac(
    secret,
    salt: 'disk-encryption',
    iterations: 1,
    length: 32,
    hash: 'SHA256'
  )

  puts "KDF: #{kdf.unpack1('H*')}"
```

Start and end are somehow the same, but the middle is not matching at all. I removed the \x from the python string to better read it.

```
org py KDF: b'\x0e\x04\xc2^Z\x04t\xddCh\x97E\xf7\xc9%o\xff\xb8o\x96\x0f\x8aA\xablg\x06\x85\\\xc0\xa3\xde'
Python KDF: b'0e04c2 ^Z04tddCh97Ef7c9%offb8o960f8aAablg0685\\             c0a3de'
Ruby   KDF:   0e04c2 5e5a0474dd43689745f7c9256fffb86f960f8a41ab6c6706855c c0a3de
```

Comment: The results are identical only the encodings used in Ruby and Python differ. The Ruby code prints the result hex encoded. In Python, when printing a bytes like object, only the printable ASCII characters, i.e. the range from 0x20 to 0x7f are printed as characters. All other values are printed hexadecimal in the notation \xZZ. To hex encode a bytes like object you can apply `hex()` i.e. `print(key.hex())` to output the key. Then you see that the results are identical.

Comment: wow, thx. i'm not so good with python and crypto at all. thx very much! i was so confused because the keys seemed not to match at all.

Answer (score 0):

as [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) said in the comments: everything is okay, its only the printout format which was misleading.

The  interpretation of Ruby `unpack1('H*')` in Python is `.hex()`.
So it should be:

```python
print("KDF: %s" % key.hex())
```

So the KDF implementation in Ruby was ok and working all the time. Only got confused by printing out the values in the wrong format.